# Swift: mainView frame is always zero in swift playground

Tags: swift, uiview, xcode9, swift-playground

I'm trying to get the `frame` of the main view using `swift` `playground` but always showing as 0:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

[image]

Any of you knows how can I get the `frame` of the `Swift` `playground`?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is much too soon to be checking the frame. Try `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: @rmaddy, that works!. thank you